# Dynamical system with vanishing perturbation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

Consider the following system:

$$
\dot{x} = f(x)+h(y),\\
\dot{y} = g(y),
$$

with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and where $f$, $g$, and $h$ are globally continuously differentiable.

We know that $y$ is asymptotically stable (i.e., for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that, for any $||y(0)||\le\delta$, we have $||y(t)||\le\epsilon$ for all $t\le0$, and $y(t)\to0_n$ for $t\to\infty$).

Can we say that the solutions of $\dot{x}=f(x)+h(y)$ converge to the solutions of $\dot{x}=f(x)+h(0_n)$? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not the case.

Consider the following (linear) example
$$ \dot x = 3 + y,$$
$$ \dot y = -3 y.$$
All functions are smooth.

However, solving you get that $y(t) = y_0\mathrm{e}^{-3t}$; and for $x$ you get that
$$ \dot x = 3 + y_0\mathrm{e}^{-3t}$$
$$ x(t) = x_0 + 3t + y_0/3 - \mathrm{e}^{-3t}/3$$
whereas, solving $\dot x = 3$ you get
$$ \tilde x(t) = x_0 + 3t$$
and $x(t) - \tilde x(t)$ will not vanish as $t\to \infty$.